# sql query is not working properly

Tags: sql

i am trying to get non matching records from two table by comparing some columns which are common in both tables.i am using sql query to get the result. my first table is  snd_marketvisits this table have properties like id ,pjpCode , section code, popCode .pop_name and landmark similary my 2nd table have pjpcode , section code, popcode popname are common and there are some other fields.i want to get the names of the pop which are not in second table but present in snd_marketvisit table by comparing popcode, sectioncode and pjpcode in both tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM snd_marketvisits sm 
LEFT JOIN snd_marketvisit_pops sp ON 
  sm.distributorCode = sp.distributor AND 
  sm.pjpCode = sp.pjp AND 
  sm.sectionCode = sp.sectionCode AND 
  sm.popCode = sp.popCode 
WHERE 
  sm.sectionCode = '00016' AND 
  sm.pjpCode = '0001' AND 
  sm.distributorCode = '00190A'
```

Comment: please read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you provide the Table structure and the SQL statement you're currently using please?

Comment: So you want us to fix your code, but you won't show us the code?

Comment: SELECT * FROM snd_marketvisits sm 
LEFT JOIN snd_marketvisit_pops sp   ON
    sm.`distributorCode` = sp.`distributor`
    AND sm.`pjpCode` = sp.`pjp`
    AND sm.`sectionCode` = sp.`sectionCode`
    AND sm.`popCode` = sp.`popCode`

WHERE  sm.`sectionCode` = '00016'
AND sm.`pjpCode` = '0001'
AND sm.`distributorCode` = '00190A'

Comment: Please edit you question to include the (formatted) code. Also please explain more *why* the query is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database, as far as I know, but if you ask for NULL inside your yoined fields you should get only the rows without a match.

```
SELECT * 
FROM snd_marketvisits sm 
LEFT JOIN snd_marketvisit_pops sp ON 
  sm.distributorCode = sp.distributor AND 
  sm.pjpCode = sp.pjp AND 
  sm.sectionCode = sp.sectionCode AND 
  sm.popCode = sp.popCode 
WHERE 
  sm.sectionCode = '00016' AND 
  sm.pjpCode = '0001' AND 
  sm.distributorCode = '00190A' 

AND sp.distributor IS NULL
```